# Matlab: iterate over multiple structs

Tags: matlab, for-loop, struct

I have 5 Matlab structs. I would like to iterate over them. My current solution is the following:

```
all_structs = [struct1,struct2,struct3,struct4,struct5];
for single_struct = all_structs
    % do stuff to each struct here
end
```

However, each of the structs above has a matrix with a lot of data (including some other properties). Also, whatever I change in the `single_struct` is not passed back to the original `struct`.

**Question:** How do I fix that? Does Matlab copy all that data again when I create the vector `all_structs`? Or is the data from each of the structs (`struct1,...,struct5`) passed by reference? Is there a better way to iterate over multiple structs?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: It sounds as if the original problem is that the struct is not a struct array. Spontaneously I would recommend that you tries to fix the original problem. I know this can be complicated sometimes, but otherwise you have to live with this overhead I believe. If you does this once the time delay will not be that bad. There is a solution with `eval` among the answers but I would not recommend it. You can also do it in steps if memory fails.

Comment: @patrik Hey there, that is a very helpful suggestion. So instead of creating a bunch of structs, I should create a struct array, which is like a struct that contains structs. Is that it?

Comment: That is how it is done. Worth noting here is that all the structs will have the same fields and the matrices in these fields will be of the same size. The struct element can be accessed exactly as an array, `numel(s(1).a) == N; numel(s(2).a) == N`. In case the matrices have different sizes you have to use `cell` array instead. These are accessed with the operator `{}`, `numel(c{1}) ==N; numel(c{2} ~=N)`.

Answer (score 3):

`struct` will not be passed by reference. You will need to loop over the elements in `all_structs` using an index and then access and modify using that index. If you need something to be treated as reference you will need to define a class for it and make the class inherit from `handle`. [Suggested reading](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html)

```
for i = 1:numel(all_structs)
    % do stuff to each struct here
    all_structs(i).data = ones(10,5); % your code here
end
```

I would suggest also reading on `arrayfun`, though it is useful if you want to do an operation and get results. From your description it sounds like you want to modify the structs.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that `arrayfun` is slower than a single `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to modify content of original structs, without making a copy, you can use a cell array of structs names.
Then iterate the names, and use `eval` to modify the content.
Using `eval` is inefficient, so don't make it a habit...

See the following code sample:

```
%Create sample structs (each struct has a data element).
struct1.data = 1;
struct2.data = 2;
struct3.data = 3;

%Create a cell array containing structs names as strings.
struct_names = {'struct1', 'struct2', 'struct3'};

%Iterate all structs names
%Modify data elements of each struct using eval.
for i = 1:length(struct_names)
    sname = struct_names{i}; %Get struct name from cell array.

    %Evaluate a string like: 'struct1.data = struct1.data + 1;'
    eval([sname, '.data = ', sname, '.data + 1;']);
end
```

Comment: _"Using eval is inefficient, so don't make it a habit..."_ why recommending bad habits?

Comment: @EBH In some cases, using eval is the best alternative. When the sturcts are given (not within an array in the first place), using eval look like a better solution than creating an array of structs, and using array elements from now on. It is important to know the `eval` option, but not using it when it's not necessary.

Comment: This kind of solves the problem, but I would not recommend it. If possible `eval` should be avoided and _if_, there should not be naked evals in the code. I would rather recommend to take catenate the struct even though it will take some extra time and memory (temporary memory overhead).